# Sequence of points converging to limit point of a set.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm learning topology for the first time right now, and I'm significantly further along in my analysis training than I am in topology. Consequently, my analysis intuition sometimes ruins my topology intuition. We recently went over a definition in class that seems like it should have a natural theorem to go along with it, but no theorem was ever given.

Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subset X$. We say $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every open $U$ such that $x \in U$ intersects $A$ at a point besides $x$.

We then introduced the notion of a limit, which is clearly different than a limit point. But, intuitively, they seem very closely related. Intuitively, I'd like to say that if $x$ is a limit point of a subspace $A$, then there should be some sequence in $A$ converging to $x$. Namely, we just keep making the open set containing $x$ smaller and smaller. Using the axiom of choice, we should be able to choose a point in each of these open sets around $x$, and construct our sequence this way.

This seems like a relatively powerful statement, and not necessarily so trivial as to be disregarded and considered not worth going over in class. My "street-smarts" (so to speak) tell me that there must be a reason we didn't talk about this. However, my mathematical intuition tells me this must be true. Is there a problem in my logic? Or can one conclude that if $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $A$ contains a sequence of points converging to $x$?

Comment: Not true in a general topological space, but true in metric spaces (more generally, a first countable space)

Comment: What about Hausdorff spaces? All metric spaces are Hausdorff, but not all Hausdorff are metrizable (I believe). What can be said for these spaces?

Comment: Not true with just Hausdorffness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As geetha290krm has pointed out in the comments, the notion of being a limit point of a set $S$ does not coincide with being a sequential limit of points in $S$, outside of the generality of first-countable spaces.[edit: as Steven Clontz points out, we can go a little bit more general with Fréchet-Urysohn spaces.]

However, there is a more general notion of a limit, where sequences are replaced by “nets”.  A net is essentially a sequence but with the role of $\mathbb N$ replaced by a directed partially ordered set. [See here for a formal definition.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))

It is then indeed true that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if it is a limit of a net of points in $A\backslash \{x\}$. The proof is simple - in one direction, your convergent net of points will eventually intersect every neighborhood of $x$.  Conversely, given that $x$ is a limit point, the set of neighborhoods of $x$ form a directed poset under reverse inclusion, so your axiom of choice argument works great, as we just index our net with the open neighborhoods of $x$ and choose a point from each one in $A\backslash \{x\}$.

Many other concepts involving sequences can be [generalized using nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Properties), and this allows extension of certain equivalences that are true for sequential definitions in more restricted settings.

For example, compactness is equivalent, in general, to “sequential” compactness, and continuity to “sequential” continuity, where “sequential” is interpreted in terms of nets.  The closure of a set is also precisely given by limits of nets, though one does have to be a little careful outside of the Hausdorff setting, where a net may converge to more than one point simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The class of spaces where this holds is known as [Fréchet Urysohn](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000080).